# How to remove Transaction Id from Sales Order in Magento 2.4.0?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4, payment-methods, transaction

How can I remove the transaction id from the sales order? I have two transaction ids in the Transaction section. I want to remove the latest one. Please check the attached screenshot.

is there any MySQL query or any other solution?

[image]